# pugixml. how to get all of the substructure from node, if not known in advance where it is located?

Tags: c++, pugixml

In all the examples pugixml which I have encountered, anywhere parse tree, if known, where is located node in tree structure. But what if you do not know where is the node, and only knows her name.

I have an example of the input string:

```
<data> 
    .......
    <name not known1>
        <name not known2>
        ........ <!-- maybe something sub node>
                    <need node>
                        <Name>student 1</Name>  
                        <Roll>111</Roll> 
                    </need node>  
        ........ <!-- maybe something sub node>
        </name not known2>
    </name not known1>
    <name not known3>
    ........ <!-- maybe something nodes>
                <need node>
                    <Name>july 1</Name>  
                    <new data>444</new data>
                    <data5>444</data5>
                    <node>
                        <data>student class 4</data>
                    </node>
                </need node>  
    ........ <!-- maybe something nodes>
    </name not known3>
    .......
</data>
```

Please tell me how to use pugixml to find and get all the substructure(and values) of all nodes "need node" from all xml document? If I don't know where they are located in the tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use XPath. Assuming "need node" is named "information", you could get all nodes with this name, iterate through them and get data from the resulting nodes:

```
pugi::xpath_node_set ns = doc.select_nodes("//information");

// if you don't have C++11, use for (size_t i = 0; i < ns.size(); ++i)
for (pugi::xpath_node n: ns)
{
    pugi::xml_node node = n.node();
    const char* name = n.child("Name").text().get();
    // ...
}
```